# How can i do memory management in my Android Application?

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, out-of-memory, android-memory

I'm building an Android Application where i have more than 5 Activities. Many of them have fragments which loads endless list with images and text (Just like any other e-Commerce Product listing page) in RecyclerView. Now when i come back to 1st Activity from 5th activity, it throws OutOfMemoryException and is using a lot of Memory. Which mechanism and how should i use it in such a way that cleans the unused memory when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this https://github.com/square/leakcanary this is a library to monitor your memory leaks in which throws the OOM exception error. It will also direct you to where the memory leaks are coming from.

Comment: When I am trying to use this library i'm getting this error..
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/squareup/leakcanary/watcher/R.class 
how do i solve this?

Comment: Try to use version 1.5 rather than 1.5.2, newest version seems to have an issue. https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/815